# How to find all branch still not merge to develop branch

Tags: git, git-flow, sourcetree

We are using git-flow to manage source code.
Sometime, we want to check what branch are not merge to develop yet.
With sourcetree, find on commit graph seem dizziness !
Do have any other way instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following git command to find all branches not merged into the develop

```
git branch --no-merged develop
```

Comment: Yes, it return nice output.Thank you @mikhail-chibel